# Element centered in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, flexbox

I am trying to simple login page for a personal project, an issue tracking application. Here is the HTML code for the login page-

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>All Issues</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8" content="text/html"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"  type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />

</head>

<body>

<header>
    <h1>All Issues</h1>   
    <h3>A centralized issue tracking system, for customers and dev teams. &nbsp;  <a href="about.html">Learn More</a></h3>
</header>

<section>
    <h3>Dont' have an account? <a href="signup.jsp">Sign Up here</a></h3>
</section>

<table id="login">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Developer Login</th>
            <th>Customer Login</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="forgotpass">
                <a href="reset_password.jsp">I forgot my password</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="/login" method="post" id="devlogin">
                    Email: <input type="email" id="devUName" required="required" /><br>
                    Password: <input type="password" id="devPass" required="required" /><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="devSubmit" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="/login" method="post" id="custlogin">
                    Email: <input type="email" id="custUName" required="required" /><br>
                    Password: <input type="password" id="custPass" required="required" /><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="custSubmit" /><br>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The table with id value "login" is used as the login form over here. I want to display the table in the center of the page, and I have used the following CSS to achieve this purpose-

```
header  {
    text-align : center;
    background : #D3E3E8; 
    font-family : "Cambria", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

section {
    text-align : center;
    background : #D3E3E8; 
}

body    {
    padding : 0px;
    margin : 0px;
}

#login  {
    margin: 1em;

    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-align: center;

    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    display: box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    box-align: center;

    border : 1px solid black;
}

#forgotpass {
    text-align : center;
}

th, td  {
    text-align : right;
    padding : 0.5rem;
}

th  {
    font-weight : bold;
    text-align : center;
}
```

**My problem is that the box is getting displayed centered properly in Google Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox, where it is left aligned.** I know it has something to do with the CSS rules for the #login element, but I have no idea how to fix it, as I am not much into HTML/CSS.

Here is the JSFiddle Link- https://jsfiddle.net/m2r1ojg4/

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. I see slight rendering differences between Firefox and Chrome, but it looks to me like the `#login` element is horizontally centered in both.

Comment: Also, try to avoid using `-webkit-` and `-moz-` properties if possible. They're great if you're trying to use bleeding edge features, but by nature they're not sustainable, because they're browser-specific and support is eventually dropped.

Comment: `display: box;`  is an outdated property for the old module of flexbox and the same is with `box-align` and `box-orient`. You should use `display: flex` and  `justify-content: center` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [user t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960455/t-niese), the problem can be solved by the not using the `display : box` property, and instead use this-

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: flex;

justify-content: center;
```